# How to support/switch between different color themes in Windows Phone applications

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi the app I'm developing uses the current system theme resources for what to display, but I'd also like to create 2 additional themes.  My questions are what is a good way of doing this programatically, and what would the standard GUI be like to do this?  Currentl my app is just a single page/window and would like to avoid using a settings page unless that would be how it's typically done.  Thanks!

P.S. - I'm new to Windows Phone and have never actually used anything besides the emulator, so I don't have any exerience using any apps on that platform.

Comment: Are you sure that you need it for Windows Phone 7 or minimal requirement is different?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own resources to do that.
Usually on a Windows Phone app we use resources like PhoneAccentBrush for the main accent and PhoneBackgroundBrush for the background theme.
For more info on how to acomplish this check out this [link](http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/create-a-theme-for-your-windows-phone-7-application/)